# Speakers showing up as playback device but not outputing any sound

Tags: windows-7, audio

I've just build a new work machine with a Sandy bridg CPU (i7 2600) and a Cougar Point motherboard (Gigabyte GA-H67MA-UD2H-B3). This uses a Realtek HD Audio codec. I'm using dual monitors (but the issue is still present if I only use one) with one DVI -> DVI and the other HDMI -> DVI and taking the sound via a 3.5 mm jack.

The default playback device is showing up correctly as 'Speakers' and when I insert the 3.5 mm jack I get the pop-up telling me I have speakers plugged in. When I test the speakers it shows that a sound is playing but nothing comes out of them.

I've already upgraded the driver to the latest Realtek one and tried using a single monitor over DVI but nothing has worked.

Does anyone have an idea what may be going on?

Comment: Are the speakers set to default playback device?

Comment: @M'vy - Yes they are!

Comment: Hardware / Software volume? Sounds noobish, but sometimes the simplest thing is the key :D

Comment: @M'vy - I tried all of that to no success. I had already tried other sockets, but I tried that again and it works if the speakers are set as front rather than rear. I would have assumed that 2.0 speakers count as rear?

Comment: 2.0 is two front speakers (stereo) 2.1 is same with bass, 5.1 is 2 front, 2 rear, 1 middle, 1 bass. Etc... If you use them as rear speaker, make sure your card can output 5.1 sound and the track you are playing is 5.1 too. Oh BTW, the sound test should work... so that's weird... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for anyone else having the same issue is to make sure that the speakers are plugged in as front speakers and not as rear speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Test the speakers on another device (e.g. MP3 player). It's always worth checking for hardware failure.